# How can i redirect using modrewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

i am having an issue working with mod rewrite.
although i have a very vague knowledge using it.
This is my issue
i have this current redirect rule set up

```
RewriteRule !(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g|\.css|\.js|\.php|^mr/.*)$ index.php [nocase,last]
```

but what this does is stay in the index.php while there is a / in the url
for example `mysite.com/about/` ...which will redirect to `about.php` in my php code...
but what i want is if a folder exists it should go to the folder
if the folder doesn't exists it should then  use the rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Put this above your rule 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d